# Projection of measure with bowen - walters metric.

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, quotient-spaces

Given $X$ a compact metric space, $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism and consider the quotient space
$Y^{1,f}=(X\times [0,1])/\sim$, where $(x,1)\sim(f(x),0)$ for all $x\in X$.

Let $d^{1,f}$ be the Bowen-Walters metric in $Y^{1,f}$, then $Y^{1,f}$ is a compact metric space.

If $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure in $Y^{1,f}$, then I wonder if you can define a Borel probability measure in $X$ restricting the first coordinate:

these are my attempts:

1) $\nu={\pi_{1}}_*\mu$ where $\pi_1:Y^{1,f}\rightarrow X$ is the first projection (the problem here is that there should be an identification as $x\sim f(x)$)

2) $\nu(M)=\mu((M\times[0,1])\cap Y^{1,f})$ (but I think this makes no sense )

I appreciate if you could give me some suggestions to define the probability $\nu$ in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you are assuming that $\mu$ is invariant under the flow. Otherwise, there is really no canonical way of defining a measure on the base.

If $\mu$ is invariant, then basically both of your definitions, properly adjusted, define a **unique** invariant measure on the base such that $\mu$ is locally the product of $\nu$ and Lebesgue measure (along the flow direction).

Simply define:

- $\nu={\pi_{1}}_*\mu$ restricted to the $\sigma$-algebra of $X\times(0,1)$ and then notice that this $\sigma$-algebra generates the one of $Y$; or
- $\nu(M)=\mu((M\times[0,1])\cap Y^{1,f})$ for sets $M\subset X\times(0,1)$ and then use the same obervation as in 1).

The outcome is the same.

Comment: thanks for answering. I think it is not necessary to assume that $\mu$ is invariant. If $G:X\times [0,1)\rightarrow Y^{1,f}$ is such that $G(x,t)=[(x,t)]$, and $\pi:X\times [0,1)\rightarrow X$ is the first projection, then $(\pi\circ G^{-1})_{*}\mu$ is a probability measure in $X$.

Comment: @Tirifilo As I said: there is no "canonical" way, I never said that there is no way. What you say is a possibility, but there are many other way to define a measure on the base.

Comment: @Tirifilo By the way, since you copied from my answer, did you understand my answer?

Comment: I thank you for your answer, was thanks to her that I could understand a little more the sigma algebra $Y^{1,f}$.